# how to make bootstrap popup wait until clicking on value typed in input in typescript 12

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

hello im using angular typescript 12, im trying to pupup a bootstrap modal when i type a code in input and hit inter
but with what i tried the popup gets always displayed whithout even typing anything

this what i tried :
here is the input

```
<input (keyup.enter)="Search()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" 
[formControl]="firstNameControl" type="text"  >
```

and the popup modal

```
<div class="modal" [class.show]="show" id="exampleModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

and typscript code :

```
  show: boolean = true;
  firstNameControl = new FormControl();
  code!:string;
  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.firstNameControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
    .subscribe(newValue => {
      this.code= newValue
    });

  showModal() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
 Search() {
    console.log(this.codeuser);
    this.showModal();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code attached seems that popup visibility relys on `show` property which initally is set to `true`:

```
show: boolean = true;
```

In this case worth to consider is remove boolean value assignment:

```
show: boolean;
```

Then `showModal` implementation should toggle popup on every enter keyup event.

Example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("myModal") myModal: ElementRef;
  show = false;
  code: any;

  firstNameControl = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstNameControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(100))
      .subscribe((newValue) => {
        this.code = newValue;

        // If modal is shown and input being empty
        if (newValue === "") this.show = false;
      });
  }

  toggleModal() {
    this.myModal.nativeElement.click();
  }

  search() {
    if (this.code) {
      this.toggleModal();
    }
  }
}
```

```
<input (keyup.enter)="search()" [formControl]="firstNameControl" type="text" />
<button
  #myModal
  id="#modalTrigger"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#myModal"
  style="display: none"
></button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade show">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work , you seem to remove the code : data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" that triggers the popup from the input can it be triggered without this part of code ?

Comment: It depends how you added bootstrap into your project. If you are not using `ngBootstrap` workaround could be to create button to trigger modal and set style to `display: none`. Please check updated code. Now every enter keyup  should fire click on invisible button which triggers bootstrap modal. However I recommend to use `ngBootstrap` in Angular projects then you can use methods from API for modal state management: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api